# Could not connect to MySQL through EF6 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to connect to MYSQL Database using EF6 in visual studio , later i was using SQL and it worked fine afterwards i shifted to Mysql then i install such this required components :

- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.1
- MySQL Connector/Net 6.8.

The error says : 
[image]

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for you data connection. Exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action

i tried possible online solutions e.g  *reinstall* this components but it did not work , 
Otherwise this i tried to add such this code to my `App.config` :

> `<configuration>
>     <entityFramework>
>       <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
>       <providers>
>    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
>         <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
>       </providers>
>     </entityFramework>
>   </configuration>`

but it face the same destiny, or event clear all entity tags from my `app.config` .
also i tried to install later version of entity such :

> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0

but  it get  : `Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'EntityFramework'.`

can anyone help me to identify what should i do then ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me WITHOUT reinstalling the Visual Studio or anything what so ever.

- **installed latest MySQL visual studio plugin and MySQL connector net**
- **removed the entityFramework Tag in App.config or Web.config and all its child tags.**
- **replaced it with the following code:**

> `<entityFramework>
>     <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
>     <providers>
>       <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
>       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
>     </providers>
>   </entityFramework>`

Comment: The error was gone but nothing happens after I clicked on the Next button.

Comment: Thanks..  You just saven my morning :)

Comment: @pArthsavadiya Try to rebuild the project after updating Entity Framework and MySql nuget packages.

Comment: I have updated versions for `MySQL` and `connector` but still i am getting the same error `

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same way as above.

My step for example:

- Install latest EntityFramework using NuGet
- Install latest MySql.Data.Entity
- Add reference all the 4 files in C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5
- Replace the entityFramework in Web.config as below:

  > `<entityFramework>
  >   <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory,  MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  >   <providers>
  >   <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  >     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  >   </providers>
  >   </entityFramework>`

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by merge some solutions :)
use this steps:

1. installed latest MySQL visual studio plugin and MySQL connector net
2. removed the entityFramework Tag in App.config or Web.config and all its child tags.
3. replaced it with the following code:

```xml
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
       <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have updated your **MySQL** to **8.0** and facing issues in **Visual Studio** **EntityFramework** integration, then I have successfully integrated and recorded all my steps.

> Follow this to get your issue solved:
>   https://gist.github.com/pishangujeniya/41a051572a471fa0311a8f4f6d0c5332

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with the same issue I had, VS2019's Manage Nuget Packages window kinda hid the package I needed and I made a couple of bad assumptions. I was creating a .Net Framework class library to wrap my DB, and the Nuget packages for 8.20.0 are named differently than 6.x.x. I needed MySql.Data and MySql.Data.EntityFramework. The second one has a version for .Net Core with the similar name MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. Pity there isn't better error reporting.