# EntityFramework 6.0 does not work with .Net 4.5 and MySQL EDITED

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

We are currently trying to integrate EntityFramework into our vbnet and MySQL project.

The project works with .Net 4.5, we have installed the newest Entity Framework version EF 6.4.4, installing the latest MySQL Connection 8.0.22 drivers, and each time we try to add a Model to the project, configure the connection to the database , and Make the connection, a screen always appears indicating that the version that we are using does not correspond to the version that we have installed in the system.

This happens when the connection has already been configured, when choosing the Entity Framework version.

Is there currently a solution that we can resort to, because we have looked for countless solutions and we have not found any. The same screen always appears.

[image]

Comment: Could we get a look at the error/warning screen that you're seeing?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to add the error display.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565780/entity-framework-database-provider-compatibility-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175529/an-entity-framework-database-provider-compatible-with-this-version-could-not-be <- comment about the project configuration in here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688023/could-not-connect-to-mysql-through-ef6-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: With these solutions the configuration dialog is broken after choosing the type of model